# Produce a differential equation from the family of curves $x=a\cdot \sin(t+b)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I'm trying to produce a differential equation from the family of curves:$$x=a\cdot \sin(t+b), ~a,b\in \mathbb{R}$$

I differentiated once with respect to $t$, here $x$ is a function of $t$:
$$x'=a\cos(t+b) \Rightarrow a=\frac{x'}{\cos(t+b)}$$
and rewrote the equation as $$x=\frac{x'}{\cos(t+b)}\cdot \sin(t+b)=x' \tan(t+b)$$
differentiating again gives me:
$$x'=x'' \tan(t+b)+\sec^2(t+b)x'$$
Im not sure how to get rid of $b.$

Comment: What happens if you differentiate twice directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Differentiate twice:

$$x=a\sin(t+b)\\
x' = a\cos(t+b) \\
x'' = -a \sin(t+b)$$

Thus the required equation is $x'' = -x$. Ha reminds me of simple harmonic motion.

Comment: that's it? simpler than I made it look like

Comment: I think thats about it.

Answer (score 3):

If you settle for first order then you have an energy equation with only one retained constant $a$.

$$ x^2 + (\dot x)^2 =a^2 $$

For the second order by differenting this once more you have both constants vanishing resulting in the well known simple harmonic motion differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

$x''(t)=-a\sin(t+b)$

so $x''(t)+x(t)=0$

is what you are looking for